# Run a function in a loop as long as specific keys is pressed

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyboard-input

I want to run specific piece of code repeatedly as long as arrow keys are pressed. I have tried to pick up as much things as I can in a week about JavaScript and have written this code (see below), but it isn't working. Right now I am trying to print a something on the page, but in final implementation I would need to run a file repeatedly. Also I would like to know a way to print the results of newly executed function without erasing anything that's already on the screen.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>

</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>

document.write("Script loaded <br/>");

document.onkeydown=initiate;

function initiate{
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
keyCode=event.keyCode;
event.preventDefault();
});
}

if(keyCode==38){
window.setInterval({a()},100);
function a(){
document.write("Up key</br>");
}

else if(keyCode==39){
window.setInterval({b()},100);
function b(){
document.write("Right key</br>");
}

else if(keyCode==40){
window.setInterval({c()},100);
function c(){
document.write("Down key</br>");
}

else if(keyCode==41){
window.setInterval({d()},100);
function d(){
document.write("Left key</br>");
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S.: Please excuse my bad scripting skills. I tried to grasp everything in a hurry in order to integrate it into a project I am working on.

Comment: $(document).keydown is jQuery, not native JavaScript, so you should include the jQuery library. You need to add parentheses when you declare `initiate`. I don't think your `if` statements are embedded in the keydown event handler, which doesn't make sense to me. `document.onkeydown=initiate;` doesn't make sense to me either, since you are binding the `keydown` event handler inside `initiate`. You can just call initiate after you define it.

Answer (score 2):

Please clean up your code a little.you are making things unnecessatily complex

Define all you functions a,b,c,d and then use the following code.If you are using jquery,use appropriate handler.

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    switch (window.event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            window.setInterval(a,100);
            document.write("left key</br>");
            break;
        case 38:
            window.setInterval(a,100);
            document.write("up key</br>");
            break;
        case 39:
            window.setInterval(c,100);
            document.write("right key</br>");
            break;
        case 40:
            window.setInterval(d,100);
            document.write("down key</br>");
            break;
    }
};
```

Note:

> 1.It is a better practice to use innerHTML instead of document.write.
>
> 2.Use keydown, not keypress for non-printable keys such as arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your code

1. `if-else` block is not correct.
2. embedded **if-block** in the **keydown event handler**
3. Define function separately
4. `$(document).keydown` is jQuery, not native JavaScript, you don't need it.

Code:

```
document.write("Script loaded <br/>");
document.onkeydown = initiate;

function initiate() {
    keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (keyCode == 38) {
        window.setInterval({
            a()
        }, 100);
    } else if (keyCode == 39) {
        window.setInterval({
            b()
        }, 100);
    } else if (keyCode == 40) {
        window.setInterval({
            c()
        }, 100);
    } else if (keyCode == 41) {
        window.setInterval({
            d()
        }, 100);
    }
}

function a() {
    document.write("Up key</br>");
}

function b() {
    document.write("Right key</br>");
}

function c() {
    document.write("Down key</br>");
}

function d() {
    document.write("Left key</br>");
}
```